# Dockerizing IONIC React-vite App gives "Connection was Reset" when accessing from Host

Tags: reactjs, docker, ionic-framework, docker-compose, ionic7

I ran into an issue when trying to host my ionic web app in a docker container. Mapping the ports as 8100:8100 should allow me to access through 8100 from my Host, but it didn't. Below were my Dockerfile and Docker-Compose.

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install -g @ionic/cli
RUN npm install
COPY / /app/
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8100:8100'
```

Running docker ps will give me this:

```
PS D:\Projects\react-asset-client> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                     NAMES
06762b1eba8f   react-asset-client-web   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago    Up 2 minutes    0.0.0.0:8100->8100/tcp    react-asset-client-web-1
ff0496344563   hello-spring-boot-rest   "/__cacert_entrypoin…"   20 minutes ago   Up 20 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->8080/tcp    hello-spring-boot-rest-1
a7459e7e3811   postgres:latest          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 minutes ago   Up 20 minutes   0.0.0.0:55560->5432/tcp   hello-spring-boot-db-1
```

As you can see, I am already running two other services and I can access both of them as expected.

Finding a fix, I came across [this question that someone asked (docker run connection was reset while the page was loading).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64666842/docker-run-connection-was-reset-while-the-page-was-loading) The solution for him was to set the server's hostname to 0.0.0.0 from localhost.

In ionic --help it shows this `--host=<host> ................... Use specific host for the dev server (default: localhost)`

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: since in my dockerfile I am calling my `npm start` script I will update that from:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc -p /app/ && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test.e2e": "cypress run",
    "test.unit": "vitest",
    "lint": "eslint",
    "start": "ionic --version && ionic serve"
}
```

to

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc -p /app/ && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test.e2e": "cypress run",
    "test.unit": "vitest",
    "lint": "eslint",
    "start": "ionic --version && ionic serve --host=0.0.0.0"
}
```

This solves my issue